# Expressing a polynom with a single parameter

Tags: linear-algebra

Okay so, I want to express $x$ using $k$ parameter , for this expression $x^2 +2x-1000$.
how do I go about doing that?

if I wasnt clear, heres a simple example.
$2x+7=k$

$2x=k-7$

$x= \frac{(k-7)}2$

Comment: This is not clear still. What does the simple example show?

Comment: example shows a way to express x using k and numbers alone

Comment: Ah, you want to find $x$ such that $f(x) = k$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding this right:

We are trying to solve $f(x) = k$, 
for some random $k$ and $f(x) = x^2 + 2x - 1000$.

$x^2 + 2x - 1000 = k \rightarrow$ $x^2 + 2x - 1000-k = 0$

There are many ways of solving now, the easiest would be the [abc formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).

Here $a = 1, b = 2, c = 1000-k$.

Comment: how didn't I think of that..! thank you very much